# ECDH key agreement generated Key Pair is always invalid in Android 12

Tags: android, encryption, aes, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I've written the below code following the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec) for ECDH Key Agreement on Android.

```java
private static final String EC_SPEC = "p-256";
private static final String KEY_PAIR_NAME = "abcdefgh";
private static final String MAC_ALG = "HMACSHA256";
private static final String INFO_TAG = "ECDH p-256 AES-256-GCM-SIV\0";
private static final String KEY_AGREEMENT_ALG = "ECDH";
private static final String KEY_STORE_PROVIDER = "AndroidKeyStore";

public static KeyPair generateKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, ParseException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, KEY_STORE_PROVIDER);
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(
            new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    KEY_PAIR_NAME,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_AGREE_KEY)
                    .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec(EC_SPEC))
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                    .setKeyValidityEnd(DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse("Aug 1, 2199"))
                    .build());
    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
}

public static byte[] sharedSecret(PrivateKey mine, PublicKey remote) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
    KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance(KEY_AGREEMENT_ALG, KEY_STORE_PROVIDER);
    //Line 55 here ↓ where error occurs
    keyAgreement.init(mine);
    keyAgreement.doPhase(remote, true);
    return keyAgreement.generateSecret();
}
```

But at the time of execution the code throws below error :

```
W/System.err: android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException: Key permanently invalidated
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:123)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.java:228)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreKeyAgreementSpi.java:96)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.init(KeyAgreement.java:498)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.init(KeyAgreement.java:470)
W/System.err:     at app.exploitr.sec.rts.security.ECCUtil.sharedSecret(ECCUtil.java:55)
```

I've tried to test the code in the following manner,

```java
try {
    KeyPair one = ECCUtil.generateKeys();
    KeyPair two = ECCUtil.generateKeys();

    byte[] sec_one = ECCUtil.sharedSecret(one.getPrivate(), two.getPublic());
    byte[] sec_two = ECCUtil.sharedSecret(two.getPrivate(), one.getPublic());

    Log.d("TAG 1st SHARED", new String(sec_one));
    Log.d("TAG 2nd SHARED", new String(sec_two));

} catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException | ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can't understand why the keys are getting permanently invalidated instantly despite of setting user authentication disabled or large timeout. As key generation has issues with emulators and I've only 1 Android 12 device (`KeyProperties.PURPOSE_AGREE_KEY` was introduced in API 31) I tried to generate and test both the local and remote keys on the device. What should be done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `generateKeys()` method creates a new key pair with always the same alias (`KEY_PAIR_NAME`, i.e. `abcdefgh`). This makes the first key pair invalid as soon as the second key pair is generated.
Using the invalid private key in `init()` then throws an exception whose error message actually describes the problem quite accurately:
`KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException: key permanently invalidated`.
The fix is to create the second key pair with a different alias (for this, the alias can e.g. be passed to `generateKeys()` and forwarded to `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder()`):

```java
...
KeyPair one = generateKeys("alias_one");
KeyPair two = generateKeys("alias_two");
...

public static KeyPair generateKeys(String alias) throws ... {
    ...
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(
        new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            alias,
    ...
}
```

---

Also it is wrong to convert the shared secret to a string using `new String()`. This applies the default charset encoding, which generally corrupts the binary data. Instead a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 should be used for the conversion to a string.

Comment: Omg, that was such a silly mistake. And yes, I wouldn't continue to use `new String()`, I wasn't sure if this would work as expected so I tried to test like that. Thank you for the insight.